# why does the this single and double quote php snippet is not working as the way we expected?

Tags: php

I have a PHP snippet and that has some single quote and double quote issue and i tried various combination but no use  even use the escape sequence but still not Getting It . Here is my code

```
echo    "<li id='Welcome' style='border: 0px none;'>Welcome'"$_SESSION['user_username']"'.'""'.'"!"' </li>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `concatenate` them properly -

```
echo "<li id='Welcome' style='border: none;'>Welcome'" . $_SESSION['user_username'] . "..!</li>";
```

And `border: none;` is enough. No need of `border: 0px none;`

Comment: As said with uchiha, I would recommend using the syntax `echo "test $_SESSION[user_username] test";` as it is less prone to errors. The concatenation is to much if their is no operations done on the value.

Comment: Please develop. So far every time I do recommend on this, peoples tend to stick with the concatenation. For me I see a clearer syntax which allow to avoid common pitfalls with spaces and quotes when concatenating. And bonus point it's easier to type.

Answer (score 2):

You can also bind variables within **{}** if you have used double quotes as below

```
echo "<li id='Welcome' style='border: 0px none;'>Welcome {$_SESSION['user_username']}!</li>";
```

or simply as

```
echo "<li id='Welcome' style='border: 0px none;'>Welcome $_SESSION[user_username]!</li>";
```

[Check Docs](https://php.net/language.types.string)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo    "<li id='Welcome' style='border: 0px none;'>Welcome ".$_SESSION['user_username']."! </li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I cant really tell your code apart, but the prober solution would be like this:

```
echo    "<li id='Welcome' style='border: 0px none;'>Welcome ".$_SESSION['user_username']."!</li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo   "<li id='Welcome' style='border: 0px none;'>Welcome" . $_SESSION['user_username'] . "</li>";
```